# How can i use awk/Grep to search a specified column for a variable

Tags: awk, grep

I have data like the following:

```
apple pear sugar pizza
pizza chicken pasta turkey
```

I want to grep for "pizza" but only grep the fourth column.
I know i can use:

```
awk '$4 == "pizza"'
```

However i have a variable named food which contains the word pizza.
When i do

```
food=pizza
awk '$4 == "$food"'
```

I receive an error
and also when i change to double apostrophes i receive this error:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ==
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shell variable won't expand inside the single quotes used for the awk program.

You can pass a shell variable to awk using the `-v` option:

```
food=pizza
awk -v food="$food" '$4 == food'
```

Comment: This does not work:. echo cake cake cake pizza | awk -v pizza="$food" '$4 == food'

Comment: can you show example where food variable is set to pizza?

Comment: @thomas: It's no different than what you did in your question but I've added it